# How to check if path is file or directory in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I try to figure out when a path is a file or directory, like this:

```
FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(path);
```

But I get this error:

> > is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context.

Ok, this is working:

```
 if (directoryInfo.Attributes == FileAttributes.Directory) {}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: Using `try...catch` will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fully qualified namespace i.e with `System.IO.File` instead of `File`. You must be having another type with same name i.e `File` in your project.